# Writing values to large array in Fortran

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, optimization, fortran

I'm trying to optimize my C/Fortran code for calculating finite-difference gradients using OpenMP. The code outputs the correct values for both serial and multithreaded cases. However, when I try to store the calculated values in an array, the code slows down a lot, vs just performing computations.

I wrote a simplified example for asking this question:

I allocate my arrays in C:

```
/* phi - field over which derivatives are calculated */
float *phi = (float *) calloc(SIZE, sizeof(float));

/* rhs - derivatives in each direction are summed and
         stored in this variable 
*/
float *rhs = (float *) calloc(SIZE, sizeof(float));
```

My array size is 256^3, and I have 3 cells as "padding" on each end, which makes "SIZE" as 262^3.

Then I call my Fortran function inside the parallel OMP region, dividing the work over different threads equally in the k-direction:

```
 #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(phi, rhs)
{
 /* Divide up slices in the z-direction over the available threads */
    cur_thread = omp_get_thread_num();
    num_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
    nslices = khi_fb - klo_fb + 1;

    /* Current lo and hi indices in the z-direction */
    cur_klo_fb = klo_fb + nslices * cur_thread/num_threads;
    cur_khi_fb = klo_fb + nslices * (cur_thread + 1)/num_threads - 1;

    if (cur_khi_fb > khi_fb)
        cur_khi_fb = khi_fb;

 /* Start timing the program */
    time0 = omp_get_wtime();
/* Run 100 times for better timing */
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        /* Calling Fortran routine for calculating derivatives */
        CALC_DERIV(phi, rhs, 
            &(ilo_gb), &(ihi_gb), &(jlo_gb), &(jhi_gb), &(klo_gb), &(khi_gb),
            &(ilo_fb), &(ihi_fb), &(jlo_fb), &(jhi_fb), 
            &(cur_klo_fb), &(cur_khi_fb),
            &dx);
    }
   time1 = omp_get_wtime();
```

In my Fortran routine, I iterate over the array, calculating the central difference in each direction at each point:

```
  do k=klo_fb,khi_fb
    do j=jlo_fb,jhi_fb
      do i=ilo_fb,ihi_fb

        phi_x = (phi(i+1,j,k) - phi(i-1,j,k))*dx_factor
        phi_y = (phi(i,j+1,k) - phi(i,j-1,k))*dy_factor
        phi_z = (phi(i,j,k+1) - phi(i,j,k-1))*dz_factor

        temp = rhs(i,j,k) + phi_x + phi_y + phi_z
        rhs(i,j,k) = temp
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo
```

Here, the suffix "_fb" refers to fill box. So the iterations run from 3:258 in i, and j directions, and over 'cur_klo_fb' and 'cur_khi_fb' in the k-direction.

Here's my problem: when I run the code as shown, the timing for 1 thread (serial behavior) is ~2.17s. When I comment out the line `rhs(i,j,k) = temp` my timing is 3e-4s. Why is there such a big difference? I am doing the same number of computations. The only difference is I am storing the temporary variable 'temp' in a given array location in rhs. Moreover, I am reading the array 'phi' plenty of times, but it doesn't seem to affect the speed. It seems writing 'temp' to the array 'rhs' slows things down.

When I run with OpenMP, I get a speedup, but it is not optimal. I guess I am missing something.

I hope I explained my problem clearly. I would be happy to provide the complete code I am testing.

EDIT 2:

So based on the comments, I experimented with seeing if the compiler is actually just ignoring the loops altogether.

I have further modified the post, to include suggestions by @jabirali and @VladimirF. I have added timings too.

So I modified the Fortran loops:

```
integer count
count = 1
c     { begin loop over grid 
      do k=klo_fb,khi_fb
        do j=jlo_fb,jhi_fb
          do i=ilo_fb,ihi_fb

            phi_x = (phi(i+1,j,k) - phi(i-1,j,k))*dx_factor
            phi_y = (phi(i,j+1,k) - phi(i,j-1,k))*dy_factor
            phi_z = (phi(i,j,k+1) - phi(i,j,k-1))*dz_factor

            temp = rhs(i,j,k) + phi_x + phi_y + phi_z
            temp2 = temp2 + temp
c           rhs(i,j,k) = temp
          enddo
        enddo
      enddo
c     } end loop over grid
```

Here are the timings for various cases (for 1 and 2 threads):

```
Case 1: With temp2, no rhs(i,j,k), 1 thread: 3.24s
Case 2: With temp2, no rhs(i,j,k), 2 threads: 1.65s
Case 3: Without temp2, with rhs(i,j,k), 1 thread: 1.23s
Case 4: Without temp2, with rhs(i,j,k), 2 threads: 0.74s
Case 5: Without temp2, without rhs, 1 thread: 1e-6s
```

Still confused :(.

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: and what compiler options and why mix fortran with C, is it possible to have your `Calc_Deriv` function which i assume is the fortran function to  be written in C?  First thing that comes to mind is declaring an array in C which is `row-major` and  per your `k,j,i` loops would be accessing it as such as `rhs[k][j][i]`.  However you seem to have your fortran `rhs(i,j,k) = temp` in the correct column major format but i would suspect this statement alone would take some time to calculate the address offset for a 3-dimensional array in addition to writing to that address.

Comment: I'm using the gcc compiler with '-O3 -fPIC -funroll-loops' optimization options.

Comment: The reason I'm mixing C and Fortran is I guess mainly because I started with some other code which was written that way, and I read in various places that Fortran is supposed to be the fastest way to do it. I did consider that Fortran changes to column-major, but the only thing I'm doing in C is allocating a chunk of memory. I don't iterate over the indices in C, and I get correct output, so I think that shouldn't be a problem. I suspect something to do with memory, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Modern compilers are pretty smart, especially so when working on a simple language like Fortran.  When a code's run time drops to zero I always ask myself if the compiler has realised that its outputs are not used later in the program and has simply optimised them away entirely.  I can't tell from what you have posted if this might be what's going on in your code but do check.

Comment: And don't expect an optimalbspeedup from OpenMP for your stencil computation, it is memory bandwith limited, not CPU limited.

Comment: Ah ok I guess that makes sense. It did not make sense for the code to finish that fast. However, how do I check if the compiler has indeed decided not to do anything?

Comment: One way to force the compiler to not optimize away code, is to use `temp` to calculate some useless quantity, and print out the result. For instance, you could define a new variable `temp2=0`, add a line `temp2=temp2+temp` in the inner loop, and then add `print *,temp2` below the loop. Since the program output depends on the result of the calculation, the compiler can't optimize it away.

Comment: Hi, I just did that...though not exactly as you said. The post has been edited to reflect the changes

Comment: `rhs(i,j,k) = temp` is an expensive access to memory, of course it will cost some time. I say again, this algorithm is memory bandwidth limited. But you say *"the same slowdown as before"*. When before? You didn't speak about any slowdown before.

Comment: Hi @VladimirF, yes I think I agree with you. And there is no way around it? Like I said in my post, I have plenty of reads to the memory (for the phi array), but only 1 write, for the rhs array, per loop iteration. Should this be that expensive? For slowdown, I meant 2-3s with the rhs line, and much less without it

Comment: Ok I'll add actual timings to the code. I always time it using the C code, as shown, using (time1-time0). I'll also change the code to what @jabirali suggested so the actual computations are taken into account.

Comment: @VladimirF I made the changes

Comment: Since you're doing the timing in C and not Fortran, I suggest that you try getting rid of the input/output in the Fortran routine, as that might make the `temp2` solution slower and skew the benchmark. So instead of writing out `temp2` using `print *,temp2` as I originally suggested, you could try returning `temp2` to your C code; that should also prevent the compiler from optimizing it away.

Comment: @jabirali actually I do that already. I thought that might be a problem, so I was returning temp2 to the C code anyway.